# In Java, why is the parent class sometimes on the left when creating a new object?

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance

I'm having some trouble understanding Java's inheritance.  I understand that something like this is possible, but what is the purpose of it?

`Animal pig0 = new Pig();`

What is happening here?  If someone wanted to create a new Pig object in this example, why not just do this?

`Pig pig0 = new Pig();`

Or if they wanted an Animal object, why not just do this?

`Animal pig0 = new Pig();`

What is the purpose of allowing this kind of thing, and what is really going on?  Note that these examples assume that `Pig` is a subclass of `Animal`.

Thanks.

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question: "If they wanted an animal object, why not just do this? `Animal pig0 = new Pig()`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Pig` extends `Animal`, any `Animal` reference is assignable to instances of `Pig`.  This is known as **polymorphism**.

So why would you want to do this? If you write code that can deal with any `Animal`, then you can reuse that code for any extension of `Animal`, regardless of whether the `Animal`s you are dealing with are `Pig`s or `Goat`s or `Elephant`s.

This also helps with the principle of **information hiding** - in many cases, you either don't need to know whether you're dealing with specific subclasses, or you don't *want* to know. Polymorphism lets you think about your code design at a more abstract level than if you had to deal with specific `Animal` extensions.  Here's a quick example:

```
static abstract class Animal{
    public abstract void speak();
}

static class Pig extends Animal{
    @Override public void speak(){ System.out.println("oink"); }
}

static class Goat extends Animal{
    @Override public void speak(){ System.out.println("baah"); }
}

static void converse(List<Animal> list){
    for(Animal a : list) System.out.println(a.speak());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Animal> l = new LinkedList<Animal>();
    l.add(new Pig());
    l.add(new Goat());
    converse(l);
}
```

At the command line, you'll see the following printed:

```
oink
baah
```

Even though our `List` was defined as containing instances of type `Animal`, we get different behaviors each time we call `a.speak()` because the first item in the list was actually a `Pig` and the second was a `Goat`.

There's a second example of polymorphism in this code snippet - I'll leave that as an exercise to you to figure out where it is :)

Answer (score 2):

A variable of type `Animal` will hold either `null` or else the identity of some object of type `Animal` or a derivative thereof.  Unless the variable is declared `final`, it may be changed to identify a different `Animal` (or changed to `null` if it had previously identified an animal).

A statement `Animal myPet = new Pig();` creates a variable called `myPet` which will initially identify a newly-constructed instance of `Pig`, but could be changed to identify any other object which derives from `Animal` (e.g. a `Zebra`).  By contrast, had the statement been `Pig myPet = new Pig();`, then it would not be possible to change `myPet` to e.g. identify anything other than either a `Pig` or null.

Answer (score 0):

It is most useful if the static type (the class name “on the left”) is an interface such as in

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you later decide to use a `LinkedList` instead, you'll only need to go and edit one single line in your code.  The two kinds of list can be used interchangeably except for performance where there are operations that are faster on one or the other.

If you take this a little further, you can move the `new` into a so-called *factory method* and hide the concrete class completely from the code that uses the interface.